# Yet another Plant People Invasion book title

Tags: story-identification, books, novel, aliens, alien-invasion

I read a novella many years ago that I think was written in the '50s or '60s. The story centers around a couple of teenagers who live in a small desert town. They notice that adults in their town are getting very lethargic, and one by one they turn into plants (cacti I think?). Turns out that there was an alien invasion of sorts, and anyone who did any harm to the environment got turned into a plant. The kids were safe because they didn't drive. I think it had a kind of cheesy title, but that is all that I remember.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be [*The Plant People*](http://www.retroist.com/2011/08/24/the-plant-people/) , by Dale Carson. First published in 1977.

[image]

I don't see a simple synopsis, but according to the Retroist link above it *does* have people turning into cacti.

Comment: Yeeess! I tried looking for it earlier (same title, even!), but Google totally failed me. This is the one. It's been over 20 years since I've read it. Thanks!

Comment: @WyrtWicce Why bother with Google, just do a title search in the [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/index.cgi).

Comment: I found it by googling for "something turns people into cactus cacti" . Seventh entry down.

Comment: Because I'd never heard of this ISFDB until now? I'll use it from now on, though, thanks.

Comment: Joe, I was trying with "old science fiction book alien invasion turns people into plants". That search actually led me here, haha. I didn't remember the bit about the cactus specifically, until I started typing.